# angular 2 how to get returned data from .post http angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am using HTTP angular2 to post some data. It is working ok, I can send data from angular2 service , receive it in my express backend.

I want to get the returned data from express. If i use .get `.map((res:Response) => res.json())` works, but it is not working with .post.

**This is not working**::

```
 let successData = this._http.post(`${this.baseExpressUrl}adduser`, JSON.stringify(data), {headers:headers}).map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

Please help how can I subscribe in .post angular2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the data outside of a callback.
Move the code that depends on the response inside the callback passed to subscribe

```
this._http.post(`${this.baseExpressUrl}adduser`, JSON.stringify(data), {headers:headers})
.map((res:Response) => res.json())
.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```